# Cross join in R with filtering/matching

Tags: r, cross-join

I want to do a cross join in R. If we have no conditions, then the `data.table` package will do it. But what would be the equivalent of this SQL query in R?

```
Select table1.value as value1, table2.value as value2
from table1 cross join table2 where table1.id = table2.id
```

consider this example

```
table1:
id  value
1   1
1   2
2   1
3   1
3   3
3   4

table2:
id  value
1   5
1   4
2   1
3   4
3   3
```

in this case my desired output is:

```
value1 value2
1      5
1      4
2      5
2      4
1      1
1      4
1      3
3      4
3      3
4      4
4      3
```

please note that neither the id column is unique nor the result set has unique rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns value.x and value.y are what you need

```
   table1 <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,2,3,3,3), value=c(1,2,1,1,3,4))
   table2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,3), value=c(5,4,1,4,3))
   merge(table1,table2,by="id",all.y=TRUE)



   id    value.x  value.y
1   1       1       5
2   1       1       4
3   1       2       5
4   1       2       4
5   2       1       1
6   3       1       4
7   3       1       3
8   3       3       4
9   3       3       3
10  3       4       4
11  3       4       3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cross join on an index by definition, and least in R terminology. What you have above is a inner join.

```
library(dplyr)

table1 %>% select(table1.value = value, id) %>%
  inner_join(table2 %>% select(table2.value = value, id))
```

If what you want instead is to be able to cross join and filter at the same time, you might have to take a look at data.table, because they can't be combined in dplyr.

```
   table1 %>% select(table1.value = value, table1.id = id) %>%
     merge(table2 %>% select(table2.value = value, table2.id = id)) %>%
     filter(table1.id == table2.id)
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Are you asking? I am trying to do this in R, not in SQL.

Comment: You can never cross join in any language on an index. This is because the definition of cross join is joining based on all possible combinations without regard to any index

Comment: You my friend, completely lack any knowledge of how cross join works. Please read this link and avoid providing answers and comments about things you do not know about: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html)

Comment: See the edit. I think what you want is an inner join, at least in R terminology.

Comment: if you need cross join, you could try using merge with option all=TRUE. you can specify conditions with merge

Comment: @AmritaSawant, how? can you give me a code sample for the example in my question?

Comment: added below. pl do vote and accept if it answers your question.